# How to place my navbar over my background

Tags: css, background, containers, navbar

I'm trying to place my navbar over the Background Cover of the website. I've tried it with position relative and absolute but it wont work. The navbar appears under the background pic and not on it. I've also looked if its just not transparent but thats not the problem

This is the code with the background image and the navbar.

```
<div style="background: url(https://i.postimg.cc/ZnHTP71s/aircraft-airplane-boat-1575833.jpg)" class="page-holder bg-cover"></div>
  <div class="navbar">
    <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">
      <img src="{% static 'IMG/logo-png.png' %}" alt="Logo" width="80" height="55"></a>
      <a class="brand-schrift">DivusX</a>
    <span class="navbar-text">
         <a href="{% url 'home:index' %}" class="nav-element">Home</a>
         <a href="" class="nav-element">FAQ</a>
         <a href="" class="nav-element">Contact</a>
  
    </span>
  </div>
```

CSS:

```
  .page-holder {
    min-height: 80vh;
    position: relative;
    
  }
  
  .bg-cover {
    background-size: cover !important;
    position: relative;
  }

.navbar{
    background-color: transparent;
    position: fixed;
}

.navbar-text{
    position: relative;
    right: 7%;
    font-size: 20px;

}
.nav-element{
    text-decoration: none;
    color: black;
    margin: 10px;

}

.navbar-brand{
    position: relative;
    left: 2%;
    color: black;
}

.brand-schrift{
    position: relative;
    font-size: 25px;
    right: 38%;
    color: black;
    text-decoration: none;
    font-weight: bold;

}
```

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

Please refer [bootstrap documentation](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.1/components/navbar/)

Comment: what? I've already read it i dont know whats the error